# UICollectionView Not showing in UITableView Header

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding UICollectionView in UITableView Header but it is not showing. I have added a UIView as my table header and added uicollectionview in it with a cell, but it is not showing when I ran the app, even when I change the background color of the collectionview it is not shown

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,
```

UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpCollectionView()
    
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

}

func setUpCollectionView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    
    
    
}

// MARK: - Table view data source




func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 3
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PartsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PartsTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

}

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var viewMain: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
static let identifier = "CollectionViewCell"
override class func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    viewMain.layer.cornerRadius = 4

}
```

}

Comment: "I am adding UICollectionView in UITableView Header"  I don't see your attempt.

Comment: As you have UITableView Header, in collection view you have "UICollectionReusableView" which is used in the delegate func: override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
}